# Requesting some research study problems on Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Someone please tell (advice) me some research study problems on Classical Mechanics that can be tackled with Undergraduate level knowledge.

Comment: You might want to check out the over-arching [Book Recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations). More specific to your needs/wants is [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9165/which-mechanics-book-is-the-best-for-beginner-in-math-major).

Comment: As it stands, however, your question (request really) is not a good fit to the Q&A format that the SE network is modeled on because it is *primarily opinion-based*, rather than factually-based.