# Why is translational kinetic energy defined only for the centre of mass' velocity?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

$$K_{\mathrm {translational}}= \frac{1}{2} Mv_{\mathrm {com}}^2$$

Why does the term for translational kinetic energy include  only the velocity of the centre of mass of a rigid body? How can we *ignore* the velocity of the different particles constituting the system?

Can someone prove this to me? I tried finding it on net but couldn't as at most places there was derivation of translational $K$ for ideal gases given.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of definition? By labelling $K$ as *translational* you are specifying that it is only the energy of the COM. The energy of motion of the components of your system would be counted as internal energy or heat.

Comment: But @JohnRennie the individual particles have velocity too...Also specifying $\equiv$ defining.

Comment: Yes, and we call that *internal energy* or *heat*. So total energy is the kinetic energy plus the internal energy. It isn't that we ignore the energy of the individual particles, just that we call it something else.

Comment: What would be the formula for that @JohnRennie ? And I strongly feel that the formula should include velocity.

Comment: We should take this to the chat

Comment: Purely as an aside, you will experience less confusion if you lay hands on a real mechanics book and read the introductory chapters. The treatments you find in the fat tome PHYS 101 books are incomplete because they are teaching process and point of view as much as actual physics and are trying to avoid introducing *more* confusion to students who aren't ready to encompass the whole subject in one big lump. But once you have the process and point of view the full treatment is *less* confusion.

Comment: @dmckee Real mechanics book? Can you suggest one? I am currently using Principles of Physics by Resnick, Halliday and Walker.

Comment: That is an Intro. Physics tome (tm), and not one I care for, though opinions vary rather a lot.  I mean a text on classical mechanics. I used Marion and Thornton in college, but the authors are dead and the text is out of press. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9165/which-mechanics-book-is-the-best-for-beginner-in-math-major.

Comment: @dmckee I am a high school student.

Comment: That's no impediment to understanding this: the level of math you need is quite modest. Though, you need to be able to apply it with patience, persistence, and precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of 'translational' and 'rotational' kinetic energy comes by starting from the kinetic energy of a point particle (which is only translational), and building up a notion of the properties of systems of particles.

It turns out that the energy factors into a portion that has the $\frac{1}{2}Mv_\text{com}^2$ form (where $M$ is the total mass and $v_\text{com}$ is the velocity of the center of mass) and a portion due to motion of the parts relative the center of mass (which for a rigid body is the rotational kinetic energy).

This development is purely algebraic so you might be able to work it yourself with no more hint than I've given you, but it is also shown in every serious mechanics book.